# invalid URL escape "%40

Tags: url, yaml

I have an http url defined in my x.yml file. In run time it gives me error like below:
http://user:password%40localhost:7001/wls-exporter/metrics: invalid URL escape "%40

This is how it is configured in yml file:
http://user:password@localhost:7001/wls-exporter/metrics

I tried double code for "@" and also double quotes for entire url, but it still does not work.

Looking for some guidance, help please.

Comment: what yaml library?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: did you find a solution for it?